# Fixing the Cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to fix a certain cells in a row for a range of 7 columns, So basically there is one trade and if move down the same trade I want it to sumif from that trade which has a range of 7 columns. But when I move to new trade I copy paste the format and I want the rows to change automatically to the new trade. So to ideally I want to fix the rows only for a certain range with the trade.

```
=SUMIFS($G$6:$G$12,$D$6:$D$12,"Buy",$E$6:$E$12,"<="&I6).
```

I am using this formula. But this is fixing the range but when I move it down, I have to manually change the formula to

```
=SUMIFS($G$19:$G$25,$D$19:$D$25,"Buy",$E$19:$E$25,"<="&I19)
```

Comment: Perhaps get the row number (row() ) and add 7 with indirect() ?

Comment: Or add another criteria that specifies which trade you need to look at in case you do have a unique id for those. Then you don't need to specify such a cramped range either.

Answer (score 0):

So just a simple example:

[image]

The formula collects 4 cells in the range - adding a sumif constraint will still work...